# Financial investment in the composition of GDP

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, production-function, saving, financial

In the production function ***Y = C + I + G + NX***

Does foreign investment in domestic assets (*i.e. foreign buying of domestic bonds*) - and vice versa - come under the Net Exports variable? Which denotation does domestic investment in domestic assets come under? The Investment variable (I), one would think, however I seem to recall being told that the Investment variable does not include financial investment, so does it come under saving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're describing is a change in the [capital account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_account), not in GDP. They're related through the [balance of payments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_of_payments), in that if a country is running a [current account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_account) deficit (usually arising through being a net importer), they'll have a capital account surplus (i.e., foreigners will on net buy more domestic assets or domestic owners will be net sellers of foreign assets, or both), and vice-versa. So if you take foreign investment in domestic assets for example, it'll be *associated* with being a net importer, but it *does not appear directly* in the national accounting identity $Y=C+I+G+NX$.

Comment: Would purchases of new stock/bond issues come under consumption then?  The fact that they are considered a form of investment or saving does not matter in an economic sense, it is simply viewed as a good (and like most goods, they can be resold)?

Comment: No, they wouldn't be counted as consumption. They're not goods, they're financial assets (they're a claim to a stream of income). The fact that they're new issue securities is beside the point; given that existing debt securities are repaid over time, we'd expect that people would have to be constantly purchasing new issue securities even to maintain zero net saving in a closed economy.

Comment: Ok, thankyou for clearing that up for me.